# How do I dedicate/allocate a custom memory location so that I can edit that location in c++

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

So I'm trying to edit a location in memory that it contains a bunch of data (create a thread using the data I put in that location). But in order for the program to run, it needs to be placed at that specific location.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dumpSize; i++) *(char*)(0x91F40000 + i) = dumpData[i];
```

As you can see, 0x91F40000 is the location I want the data at, but because the memory location isn't writable, it doesn't actually change that location's memory. 
How would I make it so I can edit this region?

Comment: For what computer (operating system, compiler, architecture) are you coding?

Comment: You need to understand much more about your actual computer & operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) operator (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)). What matters a lot is the type of `dumpData`.

However, you need to be sure that the address (after `0x91F40000`) is part of your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). How to be sure of that is probably [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific. Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), that address could vary.

I strongly suspect your code to be wrong. Very often, `sizeof(int)` is 4 (bytes). Then you want

```
for (int i = 0; i < dumpSize; i++)
   *(int*)(0x91F40000 + sizeof(int)*i) = dumpData[i];
```

We don't know what is the type of `dumpData`. Or you could code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dumpSize; i++)
   ((int*)0x91F40000)[i] = dumpData[i];
```

If your issue is about non-writable virtual memory location, you might change that with operating specific [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) changing the virtual address space (or protection); on Linux or POSIX that would be [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html).

<sup>PS. Are you sure to understand enough about address space, operating systems, etc...? Your question looks suspicious or some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)</sup>

On XBOX computers (you mention that in comments, but it should go into the question), you need to understand *a lot more* about [Xbox One system software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_One_system_software) or [XBOX 360 system software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_system_software). I have no idea about the details. Perhaps consider installing some [Free60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free60)

You should **read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)** to be able to at least better ask such questions.

Comment: each element in the dumpData is a byte btw. Because I'm on the xbox 360, I can modify memory from other programs, but because that memory is 'allocated', i can't use it

Comment: There is some [system software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_system_software) on Xbox 360.You look very confused.

Comment: I'm saying is there a way to make the location 'writable'?

Comment: @user3405539 Assuming you have a developer licence, you could post on an official developer forum or mailing list. Though it's a bad idea. Microsoft wouldn't allow/want you to do that.

Comment: Basically you're on your own. You may want to ask an appropriate homebrew developer for help.